# How to limit url parameters in Django REST Framework's Router to ints?

Tags: django-rest-framework

When I have an urls.py file like this:

```py
# urls.py
router = SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register("/?", MembersController, basename="member")
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Then the generated URL for the single object is `(?P<pk>[^/.]+)$`. I'd like for it to include the `int:` "converter type". Is that possible at all? Or would I have to stop using DRF's router and create my own URL patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MembersController` you can specify the `'[0-9]+'` as `lookup_value_regex`:

```
class MembersController(ModelViewSet):
    lookup_value_regex = '[0-9]+'
    # ⋮
```

as default it makes use of `'[^/.]+'`, as we can see in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/version-3.12.2/rest_framework/routers.py#L221):

> ```
> lookup_value = getattr(viewset, 'lookup_value_regex', '[^/.]+')
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful answer!